# Turnkey/White-label solution for custom ERC20 token wallet GUI

Tags: wallets, dapp-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapps

I've created a token and I feel Ethereum's Wallet/Mist is too cumbersome for my users, as well as Parity. I don't want to guide my users step-by-step into watching my contracts, I want to give them everything harcoded and preconfigured.

I want a web app or an Electron executable that will display token balance as well as functions (allowances, transfers, etc.) and events. If it includes its own Ethereum client that would be ideal.

If there are no good contenders, is there anything close?

Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for same thing . could you please provide any open source link of such app/dapp.

Answer (score 2):

Im doing something similar with vue.js on quasar framework, which uses cordova to distribute web/mobile and electron apps.

The javascript SPA then interacts with the smart contract.

EDIT

Take a look at http://beta.quasar-framework.org

It is a javascript SPA framework that is integrated with cordova and electron to build hyrbid apps. From here you can hook into your smart contract and build cross device applications